# Effect asking of Logo

Tags: effects

## Does anyone know how can i do the effect of R? I use any adobe tools. Please see attachment

[image: [Does anyone know how can i can the effect of R? I use any adobe tools. Please see attachment]

Comment: image>greyscale, image>bitmap[use halftone] maybe...

Comment: i know this effect. but it a bit different.

Comment: i have tired halftone. but it doesnt work. Here have 2 effect. 1.break it to digital(square) 2. fade in with dash line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably use Illustrator.

A blend inside a clipping mask would work. These are just hexagons. Draw two rows, one wide, one thin, then blend them. Put the blend inside a clipping mask.

[image]